# Search a field with special character .net sdk version 5.0.3

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

Hi I am trying to perform a search in azure using .net sdk. the field that i am searching contains '/' character. However whatever I do the search result always comes up empty. I have tried with `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` but it is still not working. Below is the code that I tried. can someone please help,

```
 using (var searchClient = _azureSearchConnector.GetSearchClient(_searchIndexName))
            {
                var searchParams = new SearchParameters
                {
                    //example location = contact/DCA-000021978/AzureSearch/
                    Filter = $"fileLocation eq ' {location}'",
                    Select = new[] { "metadata_storage_name", "user", "metadata_storage_content_type",
                    "metadata_storage_size", "metadata_storage_last_modified",
                    "metadata_creation_date", "metadata_storage_path", "fileLocation"},
                };

                var result = searchClient.Documents.SearchWithHttpMessagesAsync("*", searchParams).Result;

                return result.Body.Results.Select(t => (DocumentSearchModel)t.Document);
            }
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include details of how it is failing, beyond "not working"? Is it throwing a CloudException? Returning results different than what you expect? Something else? Thanks.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this problem. In the code above, I can't see the variable "location" defined anywhere. Can you edit your question to add this detail?

Also, you don't need to encode the filter string yourself. The SDK already does that for you.

Comment: @Bruce Johnson, thanks very much. I have updated the question and added what is location.

Comment: Could it be the space before {location}?

Comment: Will try and tell you know. Gut feeling it's not though...

Comment: it was not @BruceJohnston

Comment: Is the value in the field exactly equal to the location value in the filter, including case? The eq operator looks for exact matches only, including whitespace and casing. It might help if you edit your question to include an example JSON document that you’re expecting should match the filter.